# I have set up Docker volume but react app does not change on the fly

Tags: reactjs, docker

Hello i am making react app with Docker, i tried to make a volume to do not have to build docker every time but the app does not want to cooperate. Text does not change when I change him in IDE.

Docker command:

```
sudo docker run -p 3000:3000 -v /app/node_modules -v $(pwd):/app *image-id*
```

Comment: Do you need Docker here; can you just run `node` (or something like `yarn start`), without needing Docker or administrator-level permissions?

Answer (score -1):

I guess you missed to assign a name for the volume. If you want to assign "name" as your volume name, you can try:

```
sudo docker run -p 3000:3000 -v name:/app/node_modules -v $(pwd):/app *image-id*
```